# JavaScript filter not filtering false comparison out

Tags: javascript

So I have am trying to filter an array as shown here:

```js
    let overrides = rawPluginConfig.overrides;
    console.log(overrides);
    let passes = overrides.filter(override => {
        let symbol = override.level.substring(0, 2);
        let scopeLevel = Number(override.level.substring(2));
        switch (symbol) {
            case '>=':
                if(level >= scopeLevel) return false;
                return true;
            case '==':
                if(level === scopeLevel) return false;
                return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the `overrides` variable:

```js
[
  { level: '>=50', config: { message: "Woah, you're a moderator..." } },
  { level: '>=100', config: { message: [Object] } }
]
```

And this is what the `console.log(passes);` logs after running it:

```js
[ { level: '>=100', config: null } ]
```

Why, if the `level` variable is 51, is a `scopeLevel` of `>=100`, is the first override being filtered out, but not the second one?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to convert `scopeLevel` to a number before comparing: otherwise you’re comparing strings and not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` keeps everything that passed the test so in your case you just have to flip the returns:

```js
let overrides = rawPluginConfig.overrides;
    console.log(overrides);
    let passes = overrides.filter(override => {
        let symbol = override.level.substring(0, 2);
        let scopeLevel = Number(override.level.substring(2));
        switch (symbol) {
            case '>=':
                if(level >= scopeLevel) return true;
                return false;
            case '==':
                if(level === scopeLevel) return true;
                return false;
        }
    });
```

i think that's how you wanted it since now it logs what you want?